# Is there any way to program dsPIC33EP in C++?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c++

Is there any way to program dsPIC33EP in C++ ??

Answer (score 4):

Microchip provides a free C++ compiler only for the [PIC32 family](http://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/xcpluspromo.aspx).

As for the 16 bit PICs, like your dsPIC33EP, there is an C/EC++ compiler from IAR ([IAR Embedded Workbench for Microchip dsPIC/PIC24)](http://www.iar.com/en/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/Microchip-dsPICPIC24/), but it is not supported anymore (legacy).

EC++ = [Embedded C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B)

Comment: A pity it is only "Compliant with the majority of C++98 and C++2003 ANSI standards". C++11 (or even 14!) is the standard now, and the "majority of" part doesn't give me warm feelings either.

Comment: It's quite annoying. Microchip compilers don't even fully implement the C99 standard which is 15 years old!

Comment: As for C++ compilers, not even the ones for PC development (e.g. Microsoft) implement all the features of C++11.

Comment: EC++ seems dead and rightly so. They removed the wrong things from the language (templates!, namespaces), and left the wrong things in (heap).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I guess there isn't a big market for C++ compilers for 8-bit and 16-bit microcontrollers.

Comment: GCC is C++11, at least enough for me. MSVC is nearly enough, I really miss constexpr. You can never expect 100%, but uChip seems to provide less C++98 than GCC/MSVC/Clang provide C++11. I'll stick with GCC and Cortex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19109/discussion-between-wouter-van-ooijen-and-m-alin).